# Open source alternatives to ArcGIS online

Tags: open-source, gis

I am looking for open source alternatives to web GIS clients like ArcGIS Online. I tried GeoNode with GeoServer for the back end, and MapStore for the front (GeoSolutions). I like it but I am searching if there are others in order to have a full vision.

What I need would be: An open source web GIS where I can add shapefiles, WMS or GeoJSON, manage style, manage permissions, intersect layers in the front end, measure, draw in the map, etc. all the classic tools in a webGIS.

Thanks a lot.